C# Vector2.Reflect: Is the result wrong or are my expectations wrong?
I use C# .NET 8.0, Namespace System.Numerics.
I want to calculate the reflection of a vector on a plane.
I use Vector2.Reflect(Vector2 In, Vector2 Normal).
I think I get the wrong result.
Here is a simple example:
We have the green vector pointing upwards.
The mirror plane goes from top left to bottom right having a normal (1, 1).
I expect to get the red out vector pointing to the left.
But Vector2.Reflect( In, Normal ) gives me (-2, -1).
Who is wrong? If it's me - then why?

using System.Numerics;
Vector2 In = new Vector2(0, 1);
Vector2 Normal = new Vector2(1, 1);
Vector2 Out = Vector2.Reflect(In, Normal);
Vector2 Expected = new Vector2(-1, 0);
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("In: {0}, Normal: {1}, Out: {2}, Expected: {3}", In, Normal, Out, Expected));

Result is:
In: <0. 1>, Normal: <1. 1>, Out: <-2. -1>, Expected: <-1. 0>


Shouldn't the normal vector be inverted?

You get the same result (-2, -1) with the Normal( -1, -1 ). You get even "worse" results with e.g. Normal (2, 2)-> Out (-8, -7)

Have you tried normalizing the normal?

The docs don't mention that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector2.reflect?view=net-8.0 They only talk about a normal vector not a normal unit vector. But it looks like you're right. I added Normal = Vector2.Normalize(Normal); I now get the following result:   In: <0. 1>, Normal: <0,70710677. 0,70710677>, Out: <-0,99999994. 5,9604645E-08>, Expected: <-1. 0> which is very close to my expectations. I also tried other values that are now correct. Thanks.

.Net uses well known formula reflected = d - 2 * (d, n) * n which requires that normal n be normalized. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13261/how-to-get-a-reflection-vector
